# How to wake google glass from service

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I want to wake up google glass. I have service and LiveCard, and I want to wake up Google glass and navigate to my Card.

Is that possible?

Comment: What is wrong with tapping Google Glass and swiping to find your livecard?

Answer (score 0):

You can't acquire a wakelock when you use Live Cards, so waking up the Glass programmatically is not possible:

[GDK - keep screen from dimming on a live card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403837/gdk-keep-screen-from-dimming-on-a-live-card)

Live cards don't really give you any control of the device or the timeline. If you need it you have to implement your glassware as an Immersion.