# Live card change time to standby

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I am using a livecard to show some pictures but the display turns off really fast and we don't have time to see the picture well.

I would like to disable or to change the time before the display turns off. How can I do it (without using an immersive card) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note if this is a live card, according to the solution this isn't available currently in GDK according to Alain and not suggested. [GDK - keep screen from dimming on a live card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403837/gdk-keep-screen-from-dimming-on-a-live-card)

it is recommended you rewrite it into an immersion card and manually set the brightness within the activity do.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

referenced from this solution 
[GDK / APK for Google Glass - Keep screen from dimming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502143/gdk-apk-for-google-glass-keep-screen-from-dimming)

You can also experiment with WakeLock in Android